# Where is the best place to start a long running, application-wide, background task

Tags: android

I have a long running background task that I would like to start when the app launches and shutdown when the application shuts down. I'm already quite aware of the activity life cycle and what gets called when an activity gets created and destroyed.

I'm coming from an iOS background, and over there we have some calls that are made during application startup and shutdown. Is there something similar in the android world? I've searched a lot and all I'm finding are answers relating to an activity, not the entire application.

(Android is relatively new to me, so I may just not know the correct terminology to search for.)

**EDIT:**

I'll try an be a bit more specific. I have a background task that needs to be continuously running while the user is using the application. It will be streaming data from a server *continuously* while the application is active. It does not need to run when the application is in the background. It doesn't seem to make sense to me to tie the startup / shutdown of this background process to any one single activity since it may not be the same one activity that starts up when the application becomes active.

I am (possibly mistakenly) assuming that the OS takes care of starting / stopping background threads when the application resumes and pauses. If that is, in fact, the case, then all I really need to do is spin up the background task when the application first launches, i.e. when it is loaded into memory and becomes active for the first time that session.

Comment: The sooner you stop thinking in terms of an "application", the better off you will be. Applications do not start and stop on Android, any more than they do in a Web app. *Other things* may have start/stop semantics, which may or may not meet your needs. Processes, for example, get started and stopped. So, to help you, we would need to know precisely what you mean by "application startup and shutdown". For example, if you consider tapping on a home screen's launcher icon to be "application startup", what constitutes "application shutdown"?

Comment: Are you saying that when the OS starts up all applications are loaded into memory and started at the same time? How are you supposed to handle things like synchronizing data in the background? Something has to kick that process off at some point.

Comment: "Are you saying that when the OS starts up all applications are loaded into memory and started at the same time?" -- no. However, "application" and "process" are not synonymous, for any likely definition of "process".

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I am incorrectly using the term "process". I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It doesn't seem to make sense to me to tie the startup / shutdown of this background task to any one single activity since it may not be the same one activity that starts up when the application becomes active.

That's reasonable. It is somewhat difficult to implement, though.

> I am (possibly mistakenly) assuming that the OS takes care of starting / stopping background threads when the application resumes and pauses.

You have it exactly backwards. Android pays not one whit of attention to any threads that you fork yourself, directly or via thin wrappers like `AsyncTask`.

In addition to that point of confusion, you appear to be equating "user switching to another app" with "app shutdown". Those may be the same thing in single-tasking operating systems. They are not the same thing in Windows, OS X, Linux, Android, etc.

So, what you seem to be seeking is having a background thread running doing this streaming work while your UI is in the foreground, and then stop when your UI is in the background. The problem is that there really isn't a straightforward way of accomplishing that in Android.

One close approximation would be to create and register a custom `Application` class, where you override `onTrimMemory()`, and stop your background work when you get to `TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN`, `TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND`, `TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE`, or `TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE` -- whichever of those that you encounter first. If, when one of those arrives, you determine that your streaming thread is still outstanding, shut it down.

In terms of startup, you could use `onCreate()` on that same `Application` singleton. The problem is that this will be called on any process creation, which may include scenarios in which you do not have UI (e.g., you are responding to some system broadcast, like `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`), or possibly your process is going to parts of your UI that do not depend on the streaming. If you have none of those scenarios, then `onCreate()` in `Application` would be fine. Otherwise, kick off the streaming in `onCreate()` of whatever activities need it.

While normally we manage long-running threads with a `Service`, that is for cases where we explicitly want the thread to continue after our UI is in the background. Since you do not want that, you could skip the service.

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation. I do know the difference between "switching to another app" and "app shutdown". I was just trying to state that the background task (not process. sorry, wrong term initially) does not NEED to run in instances when the app enters the background. My intent was, in fact, to start the task when the application is loaded into memory and becomes active for the first time and is stopped when the application exits and is unloaded from memory. Basically it sounds like there is not a particularly straightforward way to do what I'm thinking. At least not how I'm used to.

Comment: @JordanBondo: "My intent was, in fact, to start the task when the application is loaded into memory and becomes active for the first time" -- in Android, there are many possible entry points to an app and therefore many possible reasons why a process might be forked for that app. The UI layer may offer one or several entry points, one per activity. And there are background (from the UI standpoint) possibilities, such as receiving a broadcast. Only you know your entry points and only you know which of them need this streaming thread, and therefore where the right spot is to start the thread.

Comment: @JordanBondo: "and is stopped when the application exits and is unloaded from memory" -- if "the application exits" means "the user switched to another app", your process does not terminate immediately, and therefore it is not "unloaded from memory". If, OTOH, "the application exits" means "the process was terminated", then you don't have to worry about stopping the thread, as the thread goes away when the process does. However, this may be some time after your UI has moved into the background.

Comment: "Application Exits" == "Unloaded from Memory". Initially I was thinking that I would need to handle some cleanup for the background task when the application exits, but after thinking about it a bit more I don't need to do that, so simply allowing the the thread to go away when the process dies would be fine. There are other UI things that will USE the data from the background task, but those are handled within their respective activities.

Comment: @JordanBondo: "so simply allowing the the thread to go away when the process dies would be fine" -- so long as you and your users are comfortable with the work that thread is doing continuing past the point where the user switched to another app, you're fine. The "continuously streaming" part sounds a lot like "continuously consuming bandwidth and battery", which is why I thought you were going with the plan of trying to stop that work when the UI moved into the background.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do exactly. When you're just interested in the app starting for the first time you could @Override onCreate().

Or maybe you want to use onResume() as this will get called whenever a user brings the app to the foreground. 
But this really depends on what exactly your background task is doing and what you want to do with it, to get an exact answer you need to provide more details.

Here is an overview for the actiity life cycle that should help you:
[image: activity life cycle]

Comment: This is for any one particular activity. I'm well aware of the lifecycle for an activity (as I stated in my question). Starting something in onCreate or onStart and stopping it in onStop or onDestroy in an activity doesn't seem sufficient, as there are situations where the activity may start or stop more than once. In fact, a new instance of an activity can start before the old one is destroyed, which would result in two of the background processes momentarily running simultaneously, which would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the default [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and implement it's `onCreate()` method to detect when the app is launched. There is no corresponding method for when the app gets closed though.

Do not forget to specify it in the Manifest file.

Comment: Overly complicated.  Just have the launcher Activity start the Service in onCreate.  There's really no reason to use the Application class, you should more or less forget it exists.

Comment: I use it all the time and find it very handy.

Comment: This sounds like what I need to do. I isn't critical that I actually stop the process when the application is  unloaded from memory as there isn't anything that needs to be cleaned up before the process exits.

Answer (score 0):

In Android the application isn't shut down unless the system runs low on memory.  You won't get a warning about that, it will just call your Service's onDestroy lifecycle method.  If you want to do it when the Activity is visible on screen, use onStart and onStop.  If you want to do it when the Activity is resident in memory, use onCreate and onDestroy.

Comment: "it will just call your Service's onDestroy lifecycle method" -- not necessarily. All `onDestroy()` methods are optional, insofar as Android can terminate the process without calling them. Normally, `onDestroy()` will be called, but not always.